# For any matrix in $A\in\mathcal{C}^{n\times n}$ , does $\lambda_{i}(A)\leq\sigma_{i}(A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Specifically, Does following hold $ \sum_{i}\lambda_{i}^{2}(A)\leq\sum_{i}\sigma_{i}^{2}(A)$

I know $|\lambda_{1}|\leq\sigma_{1}$, and Its my guess that by min max theorem it is true for other $i$ as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "point-wise" inequality does not generally hold. However, some inequalities involving summations and multiplications can be shown but they are not so trivial to establish.

Suppose $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, $\lambda_1(A)\geq\cdots\geq\lambda_n(A)$ and $\sigma_1(A)\geq\cdots\geq\sigma_n(A)$ are, respectively, its eigenvalues and singular values. You can quite easily show that
$$
\left|\prod_{i=1}^k\lambda_i(A)\right|
\leq
\prod_{i=1}^k\sigma_i(A).
$$
Let $A=URU^*$ be the Schur decomposition of $A$ ($R$ is upper triangular) such that the diagonal of $R$ is $\lambda_1(A),\ldots,\lambda_n(A)$. Take $R_k$ to be the $k\times k$ leading principal submatrix of $R$ so that $\det(R_k)=\lambda_1(A)\cdots\lambda_k(A)$. Interlacing inequalities for singular values together with their invariance w.r.t. unitary transformations imply that $\sigma_i(R_k)\leq\sigma_i(R)=\sigma_i(A)$ ($i=1,\ldots,k$) and hence $|\lambda_1(A)\cdots\lambda_k(A)|=|\det(R_k)|=\sigma_1(R_k)\cdots\sigma_k(R_k)\leq \sigma_1(R)\cdots\sigma_k(R)=\sigma_1(A)\cdots\sigma_k(A)$.

Next, you can use the following: let $\alpha_1\geq\cdots\geq\alpha_n\geq 0$ and $\beta_1\geq\cdots\geq\beta_n\geq 0$, $\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_k\leq\beta_1\cdots\beta_k$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(e^x)$ is convex and increasing on $[\min\{\alpha_n,\beta_n\},\beta_1]$. Then $f(\alpha_1)+\cdots+f(\alpha_k)\leq f(\beta_1)+\cdots +f(\beta_k)$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$.

In particular, using $f(x)=x^2$ ($e^{2x}$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}$), you get
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i^2(A)\leq\sum_{i=1}^k\sigma_i^2(A), \qquad k=1,\ldots,n.
$$
In fact, you can use $f(x)=x^l$ for any $l>0$ to get
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i^l(A)\leq\sum_{i=1}^k\sigma_i^l(A).
$$